# Where will function below statements be stored in a prototype of that function

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
   function b(){
     this.var = 20;
     ele = 10;
   }
   let a = new b()
```

Because i can see neither ele nor this.var is stored in the b.prototype constructor.

Comment: That's correct: `this` is a new instance (i.e., a new object where `Object.getPrototypeOf(this) === b.prototype`); `this` is not the prototype itself, so adding properties to `this` does not add properties of `this`'s prototype.

Comment: Why would you expect the constructor of a new instance to store anything in the prototype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store a property on a prototype just add it via "prototype"

```
function b(){
 this.var = 20;  
}
b.prototype.ele = 10;

let a = new b();
```

You will be able to access it directly through the created instance "a"

```
a.ele //will return 10
```

Remember that prototype is a single object, so every instance created with the same constructor will link to a single prototype.

Every instance has it's own scope, but shares a single prototype. It is important from performance perspective.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be a little careful about declaring variables in Javascript. Your current code creates a global variable `ele` (it's added as a property of the window object) because you haven't declared it with `var`, `let` etc.

For example:

```js
function b() {
  this.var = 20;
  ele = 10;
}
let a = new b()

console.log("ele is visible outside: ", ele)
console.log("ele is same as window.ele: ", ele === window.ele)
```

The answer to your main questions is no, instance variables are not stored on the functions prototype. Calling `new b()` will create a new object that has properties you assigned using `this`. That object is *linked* to the function's prototype through prototypical inheritance:

```js
function b() {
  this.var = 20;
}
let a = new b()

console.log("b.prototype.var?", b.prototype.var)
console.log("a.var?", a.var)
```

Because of prototype chaining if you assign something to `b`'s prototype it will be available to instances of `b` (so long as they don't already have the same property of their own).

```js
function b() {
  this.var = 20;
}
b.prototype.testArray = [1, 2, 3] 

let a = new b()
let c = new b()

console.log(a.test, c.test)
console.log("They point to the same object?", a.test === c.test)
```

Comment: Just assume strict mode and say that it throws an exception, instead of showing how to create globals :-)